# How do you add a 1:1 multiply layer in TensorFlowJS?

Tags: tensorflow.js

For my application, I've found that a network structured as follows works well:

- K inputs
- K * N dense layer with linear activation: KN variables in the kernel.
- N -> N layer with N variables, one for each input to the layer, tanh activation function
- N -> O dense layer with linear activation: N*O variables in the kernel

When N=1 I can achieve this with a dense layer of size 1, but how can I achieve this when N is greater than one?

```
  this.model = tf.sequential();
  this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [kInputSize], units: 4,  activation: 'linear'}));
  this.model.add(tf.layers.multiply({activation: 'tanh'}));
  this.model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: kOutputSize, activation: 'linear'}));
```

The code above describes what I want, but the `tf.layers.multiply` function doesn't seem to be exactly what I need.  Maybe it would work if I could construct a symbolic tensor of trainable variables.  I want a layer with 4 inputs, 4 variables and 4 outputs.

Instead, I get this error:

```
Error: A merge layer should be called on an Array of at least 2 inputs. Got 1 input(s).
```

So, I can achieve what I need if I can create a layer of N trainable variables with no input.  How can I do that?

In my application, removing the middle layer and moving its activation function to the first layer can be functionally equivalent, but in practice it learns much more slowly - if at all.  I could go into detail, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Why does it learn slower ? I am interested in seeing the benchmark that you have. The error says it all. The multiply layer needs 2 or more inputs

Comment: You can register your own custom layer. Since the 1->1 layer does not multiply anything at all but only computes the `tanh` activation, at the end of the day it will be doing the same thing as setting the activation on the previous layer.

Comment: I added a line to the problem description which I hope addresses both of your comments.

Comment: It looks like adding a custom layer, as you suggested, is a feasible option.  I found an example here: https://gist.github.com/caisq/33ed021e0c7b9d0e728cb1dce399527d